# Oracle SQL Developer -is it possible to filter schemas in "Schema Browser"?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

When I go to the "schema browser" option in a connection, it lists all schemas in the database.

If I need to find some object, I, first I select the schema in the list and filter the object name... But if I do this in some different schemas, Its, difficult to change the schema:

I tried to locate the schema by typing its name, but the list goes to the first with the first letter I typed.

I'd like to be possible to type more letters, to locate the one I want or to filter the list, like when you create a filter in "other users" folder in the connection.

Answer (score 0):

> If I need to find some object ...

How about doing it in oldfashioned manner? Connect as a privileged user (such as SYS, if you don't have any other) and run

```
select * from dba_objects where object_name = 'EMP' order by owner;
```

Result will display all objects named `EMP` in the whole database; include additional conditions to further restric rows query returns.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help you to filter schemas:
[image]

Comment: Tks d r,I tried to use this option! but the problem is have to search a chain of objects referenced in may schemas... if  thougth it could by possible to add some conditions, por ex: schema = 'AAA' or schema = 'BBB'to list the ones I need... but I think there there is no option like this... tks anyway!!

Comment: @DavidFernandes What does it mean exactly "to search a chain of objects" does it mean dependencies maybe? Regarding the part of the question saying "I'd like to be possible to type more letters..." - that is possible if you change the operator from Contains to Starts With in step 3.